# Send Cypress Mocha test reports to Cypress dashboard

Tags: cypress, dashboard, mochawesome

We run our Cypress tests locally (in Jenkins) and create Mocha test reports (JSON).
Now we would like to send these reports to Cypress dashboard so they are more easily accessible.

We have looked in to ReportPortal, where you can include the dashboard server information in the reporter configuration.
Is there such configuration for Cypress dashboard where we can send the reporter results to the dashboard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you exactly. In my experience to upload reports to cypress dashboard you have to:

1. configure a project on cypress dashboard, and there you get a "project id" and a "record key"
2. then you have to configure the project id in the cypress.json

   {
   "projectId": "<your project id>"
   }
3. finally you have to call cypress with record key:

   cypress run --record --key <your record key>